# RecyclerView during OnRefresh adds another recyclerView List?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

when I conduct onRefresh, my recyclerView adds on another copy to my current recyclerView instead of refreshing it, by looking at my code below does anyone know what the problem is?I have tried everything but nothing seems to work?

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
    //send our volley JSON Request
    //Initialize VolleySingleton
    mVolleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
    //intitalize Volley Singleton request key
    mRequestQueue = mVolleySingleton.getRequestQueue();
    //2 types of requests an Array request and an Object Request
    JSONArrayRequest();


}
private void JSONArrayRequest() {
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_API, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            listblogs=parseJSONResponse(response);
            mAdapterDashBoard.setBloglist(listblogs);

            System.out.println("it worked!!!");
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            ToastTest.t(getActivity(), error.toString());
        }
    });
    mRequestQueue.add(request);
}

private ArrayList<Blogs> parseJSONResponse(JSONArray response) {
    if (!response.equals("")) {
        ArrayList<Blogs> blogsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentQuestions = response.getJSONObject(i);
                String text = currentQuestions.getString("text");
                String points = currentQuestions.getString("points");
                String ID=currentQuestions.getString("id");
                String courseId = currentQuestions.getString("courseId");
                String studentId = currentQuestions.getString("studentId");


                data.append(text + "\n" + points + "\n" + courseId + "\n");
                System.out.println(data);

                Blogs blogs = new Blogs();
                blogs.setId(ID);
                blogs.setMstudentId(studentId);
                blogs.setMtext(text);
                blogs.setPoints(points);
                listblogs.add(blogs);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return listblogs;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard,container,false);
    mRecyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_dashboard);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mAdapterDashBoard=new AdapterDashBoard(getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapterDashBoard);
    mPullToRefreshView = (PullToRefreshView)view.findViewById(R.id.pull_to_refresh);
    mPullToRefreshView.setOnRefreshListener(new PullToRefreshView.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            mPullToRefreshView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mPullToRefreshView.setRefreshing(false);
                    JSONArrayRequest();

                }
            }, REFRESH_DELAY);
        }
    });

    return view;
}

}

public class AdapterDashBoard extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterDashBoard.ViewDashboard>{
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private ArrayList<Blogs> listblogs=new ArrayList<>();
public AdapterDashBoard(Context context){

    mLayoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);

}
public void setBloglist(ArrayList<Blogs> listBlogs){
    this.listblogs=listBlogs;
    notifyItemRangeChanged(0,listBlogs.size());
}

@Override
public ViewDashboard onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
   View view= mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.customizejson,parent,false);
    ViewDashboard viewholder=new ViewDashboard(view);
    return viewholder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewDashboard holder, int position) {
    Blogs currentBlog=listblogs.get(position);
    holder.questionText.setText(currentBlog.getMtext().toString());
    holder.points.setText(currentBlog.getPoints().toString());
    holder.id.setText(currentBlog.getId().toString());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listblogs.size();
}

static class ViewDashboard extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private ImageView thumbnail;
    private TextView questionText;
    private TextView points;
    private TextView id;


    public ViewDashboard (View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        //thumbnail=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        questionText=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.questionText);
        points=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.points);
        id=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ID);




    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please post `setBloglist(listblogs);` code as well

Comment: Hey, I added  setBloglist(listblogs); to my onRefresh under                     JSONArrayRequest(); and i got nothing, it still behaves the same

Comment: Post *setBloglist()* method code.

Comment: I asked you to show us the `setBloglist` function

Comment: Oh sorry, I uploaded it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear your `listblogs` list before adding new items. This is why you get duplicated values.

Also you're already adding new items to `listblogs` in `parseJSONResponse()` method, so there is no need for `listblogs=parseJSONResponse(response);` in `onResponse()` method, while its the same list.

Change your `onResponse()` method to:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
    listblogs.clear(); // here you clear the old data
    parseJSONResponse(response); 
    mAdapterDashBoard.setBloglist(listblogs);

    System.out.println("it worked!!!");
}
```